# Optimise django query when fetching information from multiple models

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-queryset, django-orm

I am new to Django and using Django 3.0.6.

With the following code, I have been able to achieve the desired results and display detailed book information onto the template. However, on average, ORM makes 8 to 9 database queries to get detailed information about the book. I am looking for expert help to optimize my database queries so that I could fetch book-related information with fewer queries.

I tried using `select_related()` and `prefetch_related()` but without any luck, maybe I did it improperly. Is there a scope of using `Q object` or `union()`, just my thought? How can I achieve the same results with minimum queries to the database?

Please help me with detailed code, if possible.

**models.py**

```
class Publisher(models.Model):
    publisher_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Author(models.Model):
    author_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Booktype(models.Model):
    book_type = models.CharField(max_length=20) # Hard Cover, Soft Cover, Kindle Edition, Digital PDF etc.

class Book(models.Model):
    book_title = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=False)
    published_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    book_type = models.ManyToManyField(Booktype, through='BookPrice', through_fields=('book', 'book_type'))

# I created this separate model due to havy content and to keep Book model light
class BookDetail(models.Model): 
    a = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    b = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    c = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    book = models.OneToOneField(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class BookPrice(models.Model):
    book_type = models.ForeignKey(Booktype, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
```

**view.py**

```
def get_book_details(request, book_id, slug):
    book = Book.objects.get(id=book_id, slug=slug)
    context = {'book': book}
    return render(request, 'products/book_detail.html', context)
```

**book_detail.html Template**

```
# 1st databse query
{{ book.book_title }}
{{ book.id }}
{{ book.published_date }}

# 2nd databse query
{{ book.publisher.publisher_name }}

# 3rd databse query
{{ book.author.author_name }}

# 4th databse query
{{ book.bookdetail.a }}
{{ book.bookdetail.b }}
{{ book.bookdetail.c }}

# 5th to 9th databse query depending upon avaialble Book Types
{% for x in book.bookprice_set.all %}
    {{ x.book_type }} {{ x.price|floatformat }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**`.select_related(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) to fetch the `publisher`, `author` and `bookdetail`. We can use `prefetch_related`

```
def get_book_details(request, book_id, slug):
    book = Book.objects.select_related(
        'publisher', 'author', 'bookdetail'
    ).prefetch_related(
        'bookprice_set', 'bookprice_set__book_type'
    ).get(id=book_id, slug=slug)
    context = {'book': book}
    return render(request, 'products/book_detail.html', context)
```

Comment: Hi Will, thank you for your answer. I tried it in my code and you know it worked like a charm, bullseye!!! I was able to achieve the same result with only 3 database queries using your code or suggestions. Thank you so much, I really appreciate your help. You have made my day!!!